# Athena Nested Array Structure Query

Tags: amazon-athena

Require your help please.

I have a column in Athena which is of below type:

```
array<struct<addedtitle:string,addedvalue:double,keytitle:string,key:string,recvalue:double,unit:string,isbalanced:boolean
```

For Example- One of the row is :

```
[{addedtitle=Sodium Carbonate, addedvalue=null, keytitle=Increase PH, key=p9, recvalue=0.8999999999999999, unit=lbs, isbalanced=null}, {addedtitle=Soduim Hypochlorite (12%), addedvalue=15.0, keytitle=Increase Chlorine, key=p8, recvalue=18.218999999999998, unit=fl oz, isbalanced=null}, {addedtitle=Sodium Bicarbonate, addedvalue=32.0, keytitle=Increase Alkalinity, key=p10, recvalue=33.6, unit=oz, isbalanced=null}, {addedtitle=Calcium Chloride (100%), addedvalue=86.0, keytitle=Increase Calcium Hardness, key=p6, recvalue=88.72002, unit=oz, isbalanced=null}, {addedtitle=Cyanuric Acid, addedvalue=10.0, keytitle=Increase Cyanuric Acid, key=p11, recvalue=11.7, unit=oz, isbalanced=null}]
```

How can i query this column if  this i want all the recvalue for this nested structure in athena with each column

As an output i should get recommendation value in each column :

```
recommendation0             recommendation1               recommendation2   recommendation3 
0.8999999999999999 18.218999999999998   33.6     88.72002
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are always exactly four elements of the arrays, and they are always in the correct order, you can just pick the elements out of the array like this:

```
SELECT
  the_array_column[1].recvalue AS recommendation0,
  the_array_column[2].recvalue AS recommendation1,
  the_array_column[3].recvalue AS recommendation2,
  the_array_column[4].recvalue AS recommendation3
FROM my_table
```

(you didn't provide a full schema, so I'm improvising the name of the table and column – also note that array indexing starts at 1)

However, your row example has five elements, and your output example has four, and the order also does not match. Perhaps you can clarify your question if the above does not solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Theo - Thanks for response. Here are answers to your query. No the symmetry of the arrays  is not there. Sometimes there are even null arrays. Consider i need 5 columns for recvalue in the same order. I ran the query that you shared and it is giving me an error - SELECT
  recommendation[1].recvalue AS recommendation0,
  recommendation[2].recvalue AS recommendation1,

FROM elasticsearchwqmsurvey ;    Error - Queries of this type are not supported (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID: 123f0646-79d1-4840-b8f2-db366b029d3c)

Comment: If there is no structure, how would you know which array element should end up in which column? Are you sure you want the recommendations as columns? Why not rows? I think there's a lot more you need to explain about what you're trying to do for us to be able to help you properly.

Comment: Hi @Theo - i have written details over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62549815/athena-query-for-array-column. Can you please see if you are able to help